# How to populate different <span> elements from a JSON array using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

DISCLAIMER: I'm a complete noob at JS, jQuery and even more so at integrating these with JSON.

I have researched and read a lot, I feel completely crazy with this fighting for hours on end to get this done. I have finally made it work the way I wanted it but there has to be an easier solution.

Most of the posts I've seen were far too advanced for my limited knowledge so I improvised and created if statements. Most likely not the correct way to do it but it worked.

I'm turning to the community to see if anyone can explain to a complete noob what I am doing wrong and how I can improve it.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Here's my code:

JSON

```
{"Techs":[
{"id":1, "name":"First Last", "phone":"12345657"},
{"id":2, "name":"Name Two", "phone":"1234567"},
{"id":3, "name":"Another Name", "phone":"321654"},
{"id":4, "name":"Another Guy", "phone":"321654"},
{"id":5, "name":"Name Five", "phone":"321654"}
```

]
}

HTML/JS

```
<body>
<p>Area 1 Tech: <span id="area1">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span id="area1-phone"></span></p>
<p>Area 2 Tech: <span id="area2">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span id="area2-phone"></span></p>
<p>Area 3 Tech: <span id="area3">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span id="area3-phone"></span></p>
<p>Area 4 Tech: <span id="area4">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span id="area4-phone"></span></p>
<p>Area 5 Tech: <span id="area5">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span id="area5-phone"></span></p>
```

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
       url: 'data.json',
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           $(data.Techs).each(function(index, value) {
               var name = (value.name);
               var phone = (value.phone);

               if (value.id == 1) {
                   $("#area1").empty();
                   $("#area1").append(name);
                   $("#area1-phone").append(phone);
               }
               if (value.id == 2) {
                   $("#area2").empty();
                   $("#area2").append(name);
                   $("#area2-phone").append(phone);
               }
               if (value.id == 3) {
                   $("#area3").empty();
                   $("#area3").append(name);
                   $("#area3-phone").append(phone);
               }
              if (value.id == 4) {
                   $("#area4").empty();
                   $("#area4").append(name);
                   $("#area4-phone").append(phone);
               }
               else if (value.id == 5) {
                   $("#area5").empty();
                   $("#area5").append(name);
                   $("#area5-phone").append(phone);
               }
            //    console.log(lax_name);                    
            });
       },
       error: function(e) {
           console.log("Error!")
       }
    });    

/*        
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        console.log('test');
        });*/
</script>
```

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:

Basically what I was trying to achieve was to populate 10 different  elements each with a unique ID (not required if there's another way) with the names and phone numbers of tech support agents. The JSON will then be updated through a HTML form (something I still need to battle with).

I am sure there is a better way to do this, I've tried thinking of for loops or do while but couldn't think how to assign the correct  element for each value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to make your HTML a bit more generalized. Instead of using IDs, you can use class names. This will allow you to get the HTML element you want in JS much more easily.

```
<p class="tech">Area 1 Tech: <span class="area">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span class="phone"></span></p>
<p class="tech">Area 2 Tech: <span class="area">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span class="phone"></span></p>
<p class="tech">Area 3 Tech: <span class="area">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span class="phone"></span></p>
<p class="tech">Area 4 Tech: <span class="area">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span class="phone"></span></p>
<p class="tech">Area 5 Tech: <span class="area">Loading...</span> / Phone: <span class="phone"></span></p>
```

Once you've done that, populating the HTML with your data is relatively easy.

```
var allTechs = data.Techs;

for (var i = 0; i < allTechs.length; i++) {
  var tech = allTechs[i];
  var techElement = $('.tech')[i];
  $(techElement).find('.area').html(tech.name);
  $(techElement).find('.phone').html(tech.phone);
}
```

Take a look at this JSFiddle. It might give you a better idea of what I'm talking about.

https://jsfiddle.net/reid_horton/om0n5sku/

Answer (score 0):

since your data ids and your html ids correspond, you can simply use those ids in your jquery selector to isolate the correct elements.  instead of empty/append you can just set the html explicitly.

the jquery `.each()` is effectively your for loop through your json data, then you can explicitly set the html based on the id.  note i removed your interior vars for phone and name since the operation is now simple enough you don't need the reassignment, and used 'tech' instead of 'value' to make it clearer what data you're iterating over in your json.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
       url: 'data.json',
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           $(data.Techs).each(function(index, tech) {
               $("#area"+tech.id).html(tech.name);
               $("#area"+tech.id+"-phone").html(tech.phone);
            });
       },
       error: function(e) {
           console.log("Error!")
       }
    });    
</script>
```

good luck!